# How to include button value in jQuery serialize() function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, serialization

I got two buttons in the form.

```
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger" value="Send Back" name="Save">Send Back</button>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Approve" name="Save">Approve</button>
```

When I post the form data using jquery `$.ajax()`, the form data is serialized first.

```
(function () {
    'use strict';
    function process(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        var $form = $(this);
        var data = $form.serialize();
        console.log('posted data', data);

        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: url,
            data: data
        }).done(function(data) {
             ...
        });
    }
    $(document).on('submit', 'form', process);
})();
```

Here in the output of my `console.log()`, I can see all other fields in the form are serialized, but the value on the submit button is lost.

Is there some setting to tell jQuery to include the button value for the `serialize()` function?

Answer (score 2):

You can know which button was clicked thanks to `document.activeElement`.

So if you want the value of the button you can just just take the `value` attribute, encode it and put in at the end of your uri parameters.

```
(function () {
    'use strict';
    function process(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        var $form = $(this);
        var data = $form.serialize()+'&save='+encodeURI(document.activeElement.getAttribute('value'));
        console.log('posted data', data);

        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: url,
            data: data
        }).done(function(data) {
             ...
        });
    }
    $(document).on('submit', 'form', process);
})();
```

Answer (score 1):

Try with `map()` function  and create the string like `serialize()`

```js
var res = $('form').children().map(function(){
if($(this).attr('name')) //prevent the element without name
 return $(this).attr('name')+'='+$(this).attr('value')
}).get();

console.log(res.join('&'));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
<input name="sss" value="ssss">
<input name="sss" value="ssss">
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger" value="Send Back" name="Save">sss</button>
  <p>ddddddddd</p>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Approve" name="Save">sss</button>
</form>
```

Comment: But how will this `map()` tell which button is clicked? ...since both buttons are the children of the form.

Comment: Map does not tell which button you are click?.its just take the value from button.And kindly why use 2 submit in one form .give some any difference from one to another ..like hidden visible display properly. if not please show full form html code

Answer (score 0):

I use this

```
var $form = $(this);
var data = $form.serialize()+'&' + encodeURI(document.activeElement.getAttribute('name')) + '='+encodeURI(document.activeElement.getAttribute('value'));
```

Comment: IOS does not recognize activeElement